# Plot x vs y with two values in y

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I fitted a model and want to do a plot of observation number in x-axis and fitted in y-axis with observed value of y  in y-axis too with ggplot2, something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17432142/plot-the-observed-and-fitted-values-from-a-linear-regression-using-xyplot-from). I can't use colours then I need different symbols for observed and predicted.

```
observed <- c(0.1,0.32,0.42,0.27,0.9,0.8)
fitted <- c(0.19,0.31,0.41,0.26,0.81,0.77)
x <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
```

So basically what I want to do is put to each x the two values in y-axis (observed and fitted) with different symbols.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With ggplot, make a data.frame first:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(observed = c(0.1,0.32,0.42,0.27,0.9,0.8),
                 fitted = c(0.19,0.31,0.41,0.26,0.81,0.77),
                 x = c(1,2,3,4,5,6))
```

Then you can plot each set of values separately, with some extra specification to get shapes:

```r
ggplot(df) + 
    geom_point(aes(x, observed, shape = 'observed')) + 
    geom_point(aes(x, fitted, shape = 'fitted'))
```

[image]

...or in an approach that will scale better, reshape to long form first with `tidyr::gather`:

```r
df %>% gather(value, val, -x) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x, val, shape = value)) + 
    geom_point()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use simple base graphics to get two different plotting characters

```
plot(x, observed, pch=15)
points(x, fitted, pch=17)
```

Comment: Is there a way to put a legend in the right side with this simple plot ?

Comment: Take a look at the `?legend` function.